# Why does Jupyter notebook print text after matplotlib xlabel()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

**MWE:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlabel('x')
```

**Output:**

[image]

Why does it display `Text(0.5, 0, 'x')`, and how can I suppress it?

I suspect it is the output of the `xlabel()` function but I don't see anything about a return value in the docs.

Comment: Correct. The documentation is missing the return (type). But as you found out, it is the `Text` element that is created by it. The usual way to suppress printing of the repr string would be to amend the line with a semicolon, `plt.xlabel('x');`. Many questions are being asked around this already, you might search for "suppress output jupyter" or similar.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Please write an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: No, sorry. You can search for the term and close as duplicate of any of the results.

Comment: Fair enough. Will do.